# Python regex findall did not respond

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I already did a research and find out about [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), but I can't figure out if it is the case.

I have a small script:

```py
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = 'vuejs-complete-guide-vue-course.vue.test'
    print( name )
    extractedDomain = re.findall(r'([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+){1,63}.([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+){1,63}$', name)
    print( extractedDomain )
```

This regex does not finalize and I don't understand why.

But if the name be:

```py
    name = 'vue-course.vue.test'
```

Then it works.

Someone can help me?

Comment: `([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+){1,63}` matches one or more chars defined in the character class one to 63 times. Did you mean just 1 to 63? `[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,63}`? What are the exact pattern requirements? What kind of strings do you need to extract?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vQrreK/1 detected **catastrophic backtracking** on the full string, but processed without complaints the shorter one. So you can assume that **catastrophic backtracking** is the case.

Comment: In case of **catastrophic backtracking** the problem becomes exponentially worse with the length of the string processed what explains why the shorter string does not have that problem and the longer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is catastrophic backtracking due to the nested quantifiers (the quantifier `+` for the character class and the outer group `{1,63}`)

Your string contains a dot, which can only be matched by the `.` in your pattern (as the `.` can match any character)

As your string contains 2 dots which it can not match, it will still try to explore all the paths.

Ending for example the string on a dot like `vuejs-complete.` can also become [problematic](https://regex101.com/r/jRQMu8/1)  as there should be at least a single char other than a dot following.

---

Looking at the pattern that you tried and the example string, you can repeat the character class 1-63 times, followed by repeating a group 1 or more times starting with a dot.

Note to escape the dot to match it literally.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,63}(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,63})+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start ofs tring
- `[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,63}` Repeat the character class 1-63 times
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,63}` Match `.` and repeat the character class 1-63 times
- `)+` Close the group and repeat 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LPvFy6/1)

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. I figure out that I missed to escape the dot, basically. And I have mixed the number of times character class repeats with the whole group.